# Infinite carousel doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css, html, carousel

Trying see this carousel doing infinite laps. After the last image will see the first image again and before the first see the last image.

Was used this

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

        $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));  

        $('#right_scroll img').click(function(){  

            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;  

            $('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500},function(){  

                $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));  

                $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});  
            });  
        });  


        $('#left_scroll img').click(function(){  

            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;  

            $('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500},function(){  

            $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));  

            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});  
            });  

        });  
  });
```

CSS

```
#carousel_inner { float:left; width:90%; overflow: hidden; }
#carousel_ul {position:relative; left:-210px; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:9999px; padding-bottom:10px;}
#carousel_ul li{float: left;width:200px; padding:0px; height:110px;background: #FFF;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;}
#carousel_ul li img {.margin-bottom:-4px; cursor:pointer; cursor: hand; border:0px;}
#left_scroll, #right_scroll{float:left; height:130px; width:5%;}
#left_scroll img, #right_scroll img{cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w35p0xdy/

Comment: Have a counter and move by way of percents. When the counter reaches the last one, move it back to the start?

Comment: Can be. back to the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment. But you could have each li's have an id. And then get the length of li. And then do what slime has suggested.

```
//Load 1st li.
var i = 1;
var no_of_li = $("#carousel_ul li").length;

//On right img click
if(i % no_of_li == 0){
    i=1;
    //Load 1st element.
} else {
    i++;
    //Load i'th element
}

//On left img click
if(i == 1){
    i = no_of_li;
    //load ith element
} else {
    i--;
    //Load ith element
}
```

Well that's what my approach would be. Sorry if I can't be of much help.

Comment: Tks and sorry guys. I try, but in wich part of js code I should put your code?Or I've to substitute another part?

Comment: You can't combine his code and yours because they are both trying to do the same thing, so you would have to use one and modify it as needed.