# How can I create a button that selects next image, get its src and replace it on lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to make a prev and a next button that changes de "src" attribute of the "lightbox" img. Basically when you click on a thumbnail, jquery script gets its src and places on the lightbox, now i need to make a button that let me get the src of the next and prev img ( or thumbnail ?)..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").click(function(){
        var address= $(this).attr("src");
        $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#lightbox").attr("src",address);
        $(".footer").fadeToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#popup").fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $(".footer").fadeToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox").removeAttr("src");
    });
});
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
<div id="popupslide">    
   <div id="popup">
      <div id="center">
         <img id="lightbox" src="" >
         <img id="close" src="fotos/fotoscidade/close.png">
         <img id="next" src="fotos/fotoscidade/close.png">
         <img id="prev" src="fotos/fotoscidade/close.png">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <ul class="sidebside">
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/asa.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/Balne%C3%A1rio%20Morro%20dos%20Conventos.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/asa.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/Balne%C3%A1rio%20Morro%20dos%20Conventos.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/asa.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/Balne%C3%A1rio%20Morro%20dos%20Conventos.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/asa.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="fotos/fotoscidade/MorroDC/Balne%C3%A1rio%20Morro%20dos%20Conventos.jpg" class="thumbnail" width="200">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe using .nextSibling() ? or .next()? Just cant figure out how..

Answer (score 0):

Give your imgs attribute called img_no with values like 0,1,2,3,4 etc. Use that value, parseInt it and get src based on it.

Refer this link to understand what I mean. [Infinite carousel doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180761/infinite-carousel-doesnt-work/28184328#28184328)